# how to make printable version with css of a webpage

Tags: asp.net

I need to implememt Printable version for a page in asp.net. How to implement if the page is having action buttons? I need to hide some portion and I am not able to apply css for the page.
please provide anylinks where I can explore on this even i tried but i didnot found the correct one

Comment: What you are looking for CSS Media Print. Check out this link: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp Also, you can include a CSS in your project that only contains CSS for printing as long as you define it as print Media.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at CSS :Media Print

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need a CSS like this:

```
@media print {
input#mybuttonid {
visibility: hidden;
}
}

@media screen {
input#mybuttonid {
visibility: visible;
}
}
```